# REST API: Raw Type warning extending a Generic Class

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

I have a bunch of RestController classes which look something like this:

```
public class CategoryController {

    private final IModelService modelservice;
    private final ICacheHelper cacheHelper;

    public CategoryController (IModelService modelservice, ICacheHelper cachehelper) {
    this.modelservice = modelservice;
    this.cachehelper = cachehelper;

    @GetMapping("/foo/bar")
    public ResponseEntity<Model1> getModel1 () {
        Model1 model1 = modelService.getModel1();

        if (model1 == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

    @GetMapping("/foo/bar/baz")
    public ResponseEntity<Model2> getModel2 () {
        Model2 model2 = modelservice.getModel2();

        if (model2 =? null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

So I created a Base.class which contains the following

```
public class Base<T> {

    private final ICacheHelper cachehelper;

    public Base(ICacheHelper cachehelper) {
        this.cachehelper = cachehelper;

    public ResponseEntity<T> simpleResponse(T object, CacheControl cacheControl) {
        return object != null
            ? ResponseEntity.ok().cacheControl(cacheControl).body(object)
            : ResponseEntity.notFound().cacheControl(cacheHelper.getErrorMaxAge()).build();
```

I then extended the CategoryController with Base but without generics. So I could use my simpleResponse.
Rightfully I get lots of warnings of unchecked assignments in IntelliJ. The more i read about generics the more i understand that this is simply not a good idea and only possible because of legacy reasons.

Has anyone an idea how to do this better and use generics the proper way? I thought of restructuring the RestController, and make them based on the returnValue. Which means that I need to create for every Model that I want to return a extra ControllerClass. Then I can i.e.

```
public class Model1Controller extends Base<Model1> {
    // do stuff
}
```

Is this a good API design or do you guys have other ideas to solve this problem.
Another idea was instead of extending a Base.class I could do some kind of util class with static Methods. But I need to check this out first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply remove < T> from Base class and move < T> into the generic method. It will remove the warnings of unchecked castings:

```
public class Base {

    private final ICacheHelper cachehelper;

    public Base(ICacheHelper cachehelper) {
        this.cachehelper = cachehelper;
    }

    public <T> ResponseEntity<T> simpleResponse(T object, CacheControl cacheControl) {
         // ...
    }

    public <A> ResponseEntity<A> anotherSimpleResponse(A object, CacheControl cacheControl) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is perfect. I didn't konw that i could use generics for methods aswell.
Do you know for certain why in a class the order is: "modifiers class ClassName<generic>" and in methods it is: "modifiers <generic> returnType methodName (params)". I would assume to write a method with generics like this: "modifier returnType methodName<generic>(params)"

Comment: Well. It was the way Java generic was designed. Only the creator can answer why! The way you want is supported in C# but NOT Java.